Android service not updating gps
the above code  does not update the gps from service the log cat only shows one update.
I need to update fused location every 5 seconds and As per Service class the onLocationChanged should called every 5 seconds but it never calls again even my GPS turn on almost every 5 seconds and then turn off after while but still there is no Location Update in Logcat.I need service class to keep update locatio.
type herclass TrackingService : LifecycleService() {
    private var fusedLocationProviderClient: FusedLocationProviderClient? = null
    var locationCallback: LocationCallback? = null
    var lat = 0.0
    var lng = 0.0

    @Inject
    lateinit var repository: TrackingRepository

    @Inject
    lateinit var gpsRepository: GpsRepository

    @Inject
    lateinit var userPreferences: UserPreferences
    private lateinit var connectivityJob: Job
    private var isConnected = false
    private lateinit var connectivityManager: ConnectivityManager


    override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
        super.onBind(intent)
        return null
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
        locationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
            override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult) {
                super.onLocationResult(locationResult)
                if (isConnected) {
                    lifecycle.coroutineScope.launch {
                        lat = locationResult.lastLocation!!.latitude
                        lng = locationResult.lastLocation!!.longitude
                        val latitude = lat.toString()
                        val longitude = lng.toString()
                        gpsRepository.gps.collect {
                            if (it.isNotEmpty()) {
                                Log.e("gps", it.toString())
                                Log.e("connection", "Internet connected")

                                // gpsRepository.deleteGps()
                            } else {
                                Log.e("posting", it.toString())
                                userPreferences.getDispatchId().collect { dispatchId ->
                                    repository.getGps(dispatchId, latitude, longitude)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {

                    Log.e("connection", "No Internet")
                    lifecycle.coroutineScope.launch {
                        lat = locationResult.lastLocation!!.latitude
                        lng = locationResult.lastLocation!!.longitude
                        val latitude = lat.toString()
                        val longitude = lng.toString()
                        val gps = Gps(latitude, longitude)
                        gpsRepository.addGps(gps)
                        gpsRepository.gps.collect {
                            val coodList = JSONArray()
                            for (item in it) {
                                val assoc = JSONObject()
                                assoc.put("latitude", item.lat)
                                assoc.put("longitude", item.lon)
                                coodList.put(assoc)
                            }
                            val jsonObject = JSONObject()
                            jsonObject.put("coordinates", coodList)

                            Log.e("over", jsonObject.toString())
                            Log.e("connection", "No Internet")

                        }
                    }

                }
                Log.e(
                    "Gps ", "lat is" + locationResult.lastLocation!!.latitude
                            + "lng is" + locationResult.lastLocation!!.longitude
                )

            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingSuperCall")
    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        connectivityManager = getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {
            checkInternetConnection()
        }
        requestLocation();
        return START_STICKY
    }



    private suspend fun checkInternetConnection() {
        while (true) {
            val activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo
            val isConnectedNow = activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected

            if (isConnectedNow != isConnected) {
                isConnected = isConnectedNow

                // Handle internet connectivity change
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    if (isConnected) {
                        // Internet is connected
                        // Perform necessary actions
                    } else {
                        // Internet is disconnected
                        // Perform necessary actions
                    }
                }
            }

            delay(CHECK_INTERVAL) // Wait for some time before checking again
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private fun requestLocation() {

        val locationRequest = LocationRequest()
        locationRequest.interval = 7000
        locationRequest.fastestInterval = 6000
        locationRequest.priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            return
        }
        fusedLocationProviderClient!!.requestLocationUpdates(
            locationRequest,
            locationCallback!!, Looper.myLooper()!!
        )
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
    }

    companion object {
        private const val CHECK_INTERVAL = 2000L // Check every 5 seconds
    }
}






a) nothing in your codes specifies 5 seconds, there's that CHECK_INTERVAL = 2000L (2 seconds) which doesn't do anything besides check for internet for some reason, there's locationRequest.interval at 6 or 7 seconds but at low accuracy only (https://developer.android.com/develop/sensors-and-location/location/change-location-settings). You should also read https://developer.android.com/develop/sensors-and-location/location/background since service requests are background requests and subject to limits
